# Continuity of the map associated with Neumann to Dirichlet map.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, continuity, sobolev-spaces, wave-equation

Consider the wave equation $$u_{tt}-\Delta u+qu = 0 \qquad (x, t) \in \Omega \times (0, T)$$ $$u=u_t=0 \qquad x \in \Omega, \ t=0$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = f, \qquad (x, t) \in \partial \Omega \times (0, T)$$ where $\Omega$ is a open bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a smooth boubdary and $n \geq 2$, $q=q(x)$ is a potential function and $T >$ diameter$(\Omega)$.

The Neumann to Dirchlet map  associated with above problem is $$\Delta_q : f \in L^2(\partial \Omega \times (0, T))\to u\big|_{ \partial \Omega \times (0, T)} \in H^1(\partial \Omega \times (0, T))$$ $\Lambda_q$ is a bounded linear operator.

Now if our map is $F$ is such that $$F(q) = \Delta_q$$

Then my question is how to check the continuity of map $F$.

Please give any hint or reference if possible.

Comment: Investigate the continuity/boundedness of $f\mapsto u$ then use Sobolev embeddings

Comment: @daw Actually $\Lambda_q$ is a bounded linear operator.  This thing i know. Then, how to use the Sobolev embeddings?

Comment: Between which spaces? Then use embedding/trace theorem on the image space.

Comment: @daw I have edited the question.